# Three consecutive characters that are also alphabetical

Tags: python-3.x

Write a program that accepts a word as input and determines whether or not it has three consecutive letters that are also consecutive letters in the alphabet.

This one has been hard for me. My though process was to use ord() and get a mean, and if the mean = the 2nd character it was right.

```
word = input("Please enter a word:")

n = len(word)

for i in range(n-2):
i = 0
if ord (word [i+1]) - ord (word [i]) == 1:
    print("This works!")

elif ord (word [i+2] - ord (word [i+1] - ord (word [i]) == 1:
    print ("This also works.

else:
    print("This doesn't work.")
```

Comment: There are several syntax/indentation errors in your program, so it won't even pass the compile stage - please provide a program that actually runs. Some comments about what I think you wanted to write: 1. Why the first `if` condition that only checks two letters? 2. How should the mean of the three letters help? It would determine `ace` to be consecutive...

Answer (score 1):

Using the mean is not a good idea. The mean of `8,9,10` is `9`, but so is the mean of `5,9,13`.

How about doing what the question states:

```
def consec(s, n=3):
    l = len(s)
    if l < n:
        raise ValueError("String too short to contain repetition of length {}".format(n))
    for i in range(l-2):
        # Check if you get the same letter by adding 1 or 2 to the next ones
        # or by substracting 1 or 2...
        if ord(s[i]) == ord(s[i+1])+1 == ord(s[i+2])+2 or \
           ord(s[i]) == ord(s[i+1])-1 == ord(s[i+2])-2:
            return s[i:i+3]
    return ""
```

This is case-sensitive, by the way:

```
In [11]: consec("cba")
Out[11]: 'cba'

In [12]: consec("Abc")
Out[12]: ''

In [13]: consec("cdskj sdoifsdjflkduf sdfjstudfu0gnfgsba")
Out[13]: 'stu'
```